# I cannot perform the login operation from my database due php api or android error

Tags: php, android, mysql

In my android program by running the php file for login of the users but my file is not running. Below is all the relevant code:

**Php File(login.php)**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM adminlogin_table WHERE email= '$email' ";

    $response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $result = array();
    $result['login'] = array();

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1 ) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);

        if ( password_verify($password, $row['password']) ) {

            $index['name'] = $row['name'];
            $index['email'] = $row['email'];
            $index['id'] = $row['id'];

            array_push($result['login'], $index);

            $result['success'] = "1";
            $result['message'] = "success";
            echo json_encode($result);

            mysqli_close($conn);

        } else {

            $result['success'] = "0";
            $result['message'] = "error";
            echo json_encode($result);

            mysqli_close($conn);

        }

    }

}

?>
```

**Xml file(activity_admin_login)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/back"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="157dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtwho"
        android:layout_width="357dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="    Admin login"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/amarante" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shapeemail"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shapeemail"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"/>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="342dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shapelogin"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Log In" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutpassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />



</LinearLayout>
```

**Java file of above xml(admin_login)**

```
package com.example.androidloginandregister;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Admin_Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText email, password;
    private Button btn_login;
    private ProgressBar loading;
    private static String URL_LOGIN = "https://ep3.virtualmist.com/admin_login.php";
    AdminSessionManager adminsessionManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin__login);
        adminsessionManager = new AdminSessionManager(this);


        loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);


        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String mPass = password.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()) {
                    Login(mEmail, mPass);

                } else {
                    email.setError("Please insert Email");
                    password.setError("Please insert Password");
                }

            }
        });

    }





    private void Login(final String email, final String password) {
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                            String success =jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");
                            if (success.equals("1")){
                                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject object =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String name= object.getString("name").trim();
                                    String email=object.getString("email").trim();
                                   String id=object.getString("id").trim();


                                   adminsessionManager.createSession(name,email,id);

                                    Intent intent=new Intent(Admin_Login.this,Admin_homepage.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("name",name);
                                    intent.putExtra("email",email);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }
                            }else{
                                System.out.println(response);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(Admin_Login.this, "Error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        Toast.makeText(Admin_Login.this, "Error"+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params =new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email",email);
                params.put("password",password);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

**Session manager java class for managing login**

```
package com.example.androidloginandregister;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SessionManager {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public Context context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE=0;
    private static final String PREF_NAME="LOGIN";
    private static final String LOGIN="IS_LOGIN";
    public static final String NAME="NAME";
    public static final String EMAIL="EMAIL";
    public static final String ID="ID";

    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        }
    public void createSession(String name,String email,String id) {
        editor.putBoolean(LOGIN,true);
        editor.putString(NAME,name);
        editor.putString(EMAIL,email);
        editor.putString(ID,id);
        editor.apply();
    }
    public boolean isLoggin(){
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGIN,false);
    }
    public void checkLogin(){
        if(!this.isLoggin()){
            Intent i =new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((HomeActivity) context).finish();
        }
    }
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetail(){
        HashMap<String, String> user=new HashMap<>();
        user.put(NAME,sharedPreferences.getString(NAME,null));
        user.put(EMAIL,sharedPreferences.getString(EMAIL,null));
        user.put(ID,sharedPreferences.getString(ID,null));
        return user;
    }
    public void logout(){
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent i=new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
        ((HomeActivity) context).finish();


    }
}
```

**Error on run**

```
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 1888 bytes, containing 1 windows, 11 views
I/System.out: {"login":[],"success":"0","message":"error"}
```

Comment: Please share your code and mention what you have done so developers can you help

Comment: Yes i have submitted the code please help

Comment: @user3783243 This noise has been removed to keep the question on topic.